# Javascript : round float number issue

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have a problem with rounding float number. Here is the source code, very simple :

```js
a = '2.3'
result = parseFloat(a) + 0.01
console.log(result)
```

Console displays `2.3099999999999996` instead of `2.31` You can try here : [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fh9bj83u/)

Have you a solution ? Thank you in advance, cordially

Comment: It's not clear what "problem" you want to solve. The difference between 2.3.0999... and 2.31 is insignificant for any calculations.

Comment: No is significant, because in my bill, I must display the number with 2 digits after the dot after rounding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `toFixed` to trim to 2 decimal places.

```
result = (parseFloat(a)+0.01).toFixed(2)
"2.31"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you deserve +100000000, solved. toFixed() method is magic because it avoid me to use substr() method.